# JSP session invalidation doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, invalidation

I have 3 JSP files :
login.jsp :

```
...
    <body>
      <font face="tahoma" size="2">
        <form action="log" METHOD="POST">
            <p>login:</p>
            <input type="text" name=login value="person" />      
            <p>password:</p>
            <input type="password" name=password value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="OK" />
      </font>                                                   
    </body>
.....
```

logout.jsp

```
...
    <body>
      <font face="tahoma" size="2">
        session id : ${sessionScope.sesId}</p>       
        user : ${sessionScope.userName}</p>
    <h3>Logout page</h3> 
        <form action="logout" METHOD="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="in" value="log in again" />
      </font>                                                   
    </body>
....
```

logged.jsp

```
....
....
```

and servlet for login.jsp

```
...
        HttpSession ses = request.getSession(false);            
        if (ses == null) {                
            ses = request.getSession();            
            ses.setAttribute("userName", login);
            ses.setAttribute("sesId", ses.getId());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/logged.jsp").forward(request,response);                    
        }else {
            ses.invalidate();                                
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/logout.jsp").forward(request,response);                    
        }
...
```

NetBeansIDE 7.4
Tomcat on localhost Windows 7

When I start project (Run / Run Project) it allways redirect to logout.jsp . sesId and userName are null (or empty ?)

Why ?

Comment: Because ses is not null apparently. You will probably want to extend your session check to seeing if ses is not null OR that the session does not contain a sesId attribute.

Answer (score 2):

JSPs *create* a session unless explicitly configured not to.

Instead of checking for the existence of a session check for a value *in* the session.

Answer (score 1):

The session object itself is not going to be null unless maybe the user has cookies disabled (even then I don't think it would be null).  You need to check an attribute for null instead.

```
  String username = (String)ses.getAttribute("userName");
  if(username == null)
```